# optional line break for long strings

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am writing an excel file using openxlsx. It contains a column (with a specified width) with strings, that sometimes are longer than the width of the column.

Is there a way for the string to make an automatic line break as soon as the string has the length of the column dimension width?

I've so far only found fixed solutions, like

```
worksheet.cell('A1').value = "Line 1\nLine 2"
```

Comment: `worksheet.cell('A1').style.alignment.wrap_text = True` if it works as the `Wrap Text` feature in Excel does, you should be fine with that.

Comment: this is exactly what I was asking for, though I found out it wasn't what I was actually searching for. But the wrap_text made me find the right solution. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Comment: feel free to post in the comment of the answer what you were actually looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`worksheet.cell('A1').style.alignment.wrap_text = True`

If it works as the Wrap Text feature in Excel does, you should be fine with that.